# How to import python module that's distributed as a shared objects library?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A vendor is distributing their python library as a single .so file.  How do I import it?

Let's say I have this file:

```
 /path/to/abc.so
```

I have set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include /path/to as well as /path/to/abc.so.  In python, I tried to

```
import abc
```

and it's not finding it.

Comment: already exported...

Comment: If it is a Python module, put `/path/to/` on the PYTHONPATH.